# How can I return from power-saving mode in Android 2.3?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, screen, battery-life, screen-brightness, screen-timeout

I'm using a Samsung Galaxy S II Epic (with Android version 2.3.6 installed), and whenever my phone reaches 10% battery life it prompts me to turn on power-saving mode (and I do).

However, once my phone is fully charged, I'd like to turn off the settings that power-saving mode comprises (lowered screen brightness, shorter display timeout, etc.)

I see no way to do this in Android except by manually going through the settings and resetting them to the non-power-saving-mode levels. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Total guess here: press and hold the power button. Is there a Power Saving option in the popup menu?

Answer (score 0):

Try a swipe down on the top status bar, don't you see a toolbar with a button to turn it off ?

If you don't see that probably you can customize the buttons on them and add what you wanted to it.

Hope it helps.